# ASP.NET c# - RadioButtons not grouped

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0, radio-button

I have a GridView and in its OnRowDataBound callback I am adding a new cell and to that cell I'm adding a RadioButton. I've set the GroupName on the radio button, but I can still select more than one button at a time.

How can I make them grouped so that only one radio button can be selected within the group.

**EDIT** - This is my code:

```
    // Add the radio button to select if this purchased address
    // is set the the home address of the contact
    e.Row.Cells.AddAt(0, new TableCell());
    RadioButton rbSetAddress = new RadioButton();
    rbSetAddress.ID = "rdSetAddress" + e.Row.Cells[2].Text;
    rbSetAddress.GroupName = "SetAddress";
    e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(rbSetAddress);
```

So I'm setting a unique ID and the same GroupName. ASP.NET is NOT setting the name attribute of the input to the GroupName. So I can select as many radio buttons as I want. This is not what I want to happen. I want to be able to select one and only one in the group identified by the GroupName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/How_group_RButtons.aspx

http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3623096/ASPNET-Tip-Using-RadioButton-Controls-in-a-Repeater.htm

Basically, when in a repeater of any kind (which a GridView is), the names are no longer all the same from the group property as a result of the way asp.net names things inside a repeater (essentially each control gets a prefix to make it unique).

Comment: I dont want a whole list in a single cell. I want one button per row.

Comment: You'll end up having to use javascript after the fact to normalize the names from what I can tell.  Hassles like this are why I switch to MVC.

Comment: i used the javascript option. MS are a bunch of idiots at times.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are giving different names to the radiobuttons on codebehind?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
                rb.ID = "rb"+i;
                rb.GroupName="rbGroup";
                GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Controls.Add(rb);
            }
```

Comment: im not setting anything on the radio button at this point besides giving them all the same GroupName.

Comment: No he needs the *same* names in the html, which it appears asp.net webforms repeaters do a poor job of.